# Proof in calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that, if ${f(x)}$ is any function, ${f(x) + f(-x)}$ is an even function while ${f(x) - f(-x)}$ is an odd function.

Thank you!

Note: I have used this theorem a lot of time. And I can prove it by taking specific functions. But, I have no idea about how to prove it for a general function ${f(x)}$. Even if someone can give me hints about how I should proceed, it will be really helpful. :))

Comment: Here's your hint: just replace $x$ with $-x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Just think this way: What property does a function obey so that you can call it even? $g(x)=g(-x)$. And similarly $g(x)=-g(-x)$ for the odd one. Now verify that $g(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$ is even(What is $g(x)$ and what is $g(-x)$? Do you find them equal?) .Similarly for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Proof:

Let $g(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$:

Then, $g(-x) = f(-x) + f(x) = g(x)$ so it is even

Let $h(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$:

Then, $-h(-x) = -f(-x) + f(x) = h(x)$ so it is odd

Comment: Thank you! The thought of taking them as separate functions never crossed my mind! :)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(-x) + f(-(-x))=f(-x)+f(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$$
$$-[f(-x) - f(-(-x))]=-[f(-x) - f(x)]=-f(-x)+f(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$$